# While Migrating from Silverlight, if we convert .xaml file into .aspx file, will the logic written in .cs file work same

Tags: asp.net, html, xaml, silverlight

I have web application made in Silverlight which contains approximate 750+ files. Project also uses telerik components. By the October 2021 Microsoft will end the overall support for Silverlight5. 
So I want to migrate my application to HTML5. While Migrating if we convert .xaml file into .aspx file, will the logic written in .cs file work same. Or is any other Javascript framework recommendable for easy conversion. Also would like to know is Telerik components compatible with HTML5.

Comment: That’s impossible to say. We don’t know what the logic is and how it is connected to anything.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of writting there is not a reliable tool that can convert Silverlight to HTML, especially if you use third party components such as Telerik.

If there is a possibility, try porting your project to WPF. The task is much easier as you would not have to rewrite most of your logic.